# Tab-Delimiting a Non-Delimited Text Report

Tags: python

I am writing a script to parse out and tab-delimit a text report. The report has 17 columns with no delimiters, so my current solution is to write the lines to a list using specific position indexes which I am calling from variables.

Example code below is for 3 columns, but for the full report the `datafile_lines.append()` line lists out all 17 columns (and 17 variables). It takes several minutes to process a report with 13,000+ lines. I'm assuming there is a better way of doing this.

```
datafile_lines = []
col1 = [0,12]
col2 = [13,21]
col3 = [22,25]

with open("RawReport.txt","r") as datafile:
    for line in datafile:
        datafile_lines.append(line[col1[0]: col1[1]].strip()+"\t"+
                              line[col2[0]: col2[1]].strip()+"\t"+
                              line[col3[0]: col3[1]].strip()+"\n")
```

Comment: Can you share your RawReport.txt to run some tests?

Comment: I hesitate to post an answer without an example of (part of) `RawReport.txt`, but I suspect that [Pandas' string methods](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.html) could speed this up.

Comment: is your final goal to write this to a file?

Comment: You could use `str.join()` method and a list comprehension to create what is being appended, and even put that in another list comp and get rid of the explicit call to `append()`. To make sure this is done correctly, it would be *very* useful to have some sample input…

Answer (score 1):

I can't explain several minutes for a modest 13K lines to process, but you can get some speedup by joining strings instead of concatenating them with `+`. In addition, the `:` operator creates `slice` objects for indexing. You can use `slice` directly and make your code easier to write.

```
columns = [(0,12), (13,21), (22,25)]
col_slices = [slice(*pos) for pos in columns]

with open("RawReport.txt") as datafile:
    datafile_lines = ["\t".join(line[col].strip() for col in col_slices)  
            for line in datafile]
```

Answer (score 0):

It really would help to have your input textfile. I created a textfile for testing purposes, which consists of 20000 lines and 30 characters in each line. Even though i find the solution from @tdelaney nice, i timed it as well as your original code with the following result for 100 runs:

```
original code:   1.06 s
tdelaneys code:  0.81 s
my code:         0.57 s
```

So here is my take. Replace file_name with your actual file:

```
col1 = [0, 12]
col2 = [13, 21]
col3 = [22, 25]

with open(file_name, "r") as file:
    data = ["\t".join([f[0:12], f[13:21], f[22:25]])+"\n" for f in file]
```

[Here is a link to the test-textfile i used](https://megafile.cc/d/gAWN/testfile)

Comment: I don't think you need to define `col1`, `col2`, and `col3` if you're not using them.

Comment: @CrazyChucky youre right - lazy move